# Move non-sequential files to new directory

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I have no previous programming experience. I know this question has been asked before or the answer is out there but I, for the life of me, cannot find it. I have searched google for hours trying to figure this out. I am working on a Red Hat Linux computer and it is in bash.

I have a directory of files 0-500 in /directory/.

They are named as such,
/directory/filename_001, /directory/filename_002, and so forth.

After running my analysis for my research, I have a listofnumbers.txt (txt file, with each row being a new number) of the numbers that I am interested in. For example,

```
015 
124
187
345
412
```

A) Run a command from the list of files the files from the list of numbers? Our code looks like this:

```
g09slurm filename_001.com filename_001.log
```

Is there a way to write something like:

```
  find value (row1 of listofnumbers.txt) then g09slurm filename_row1value.com filename_row1value.log
  find value (row2 of listofnumbers.txt) then g09slurm filename_row2value.com filename_row2value.log
  find value (row3 of listofnumbers.txt) then g09slurm filename_row3value.com filename_row2value.log
```

etc etc

B) Move the selected files from the list to a new directory, so I can rename them sequentially, then run a sequential number command?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to use Stack Overflow effectively. In the meantime, maybe [Rent A Coder](http://www.rentacoder.com) or [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com) can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

First, read the list of files into an array:

```
readarray myarray < /path/to/filename.txt
```

Next, we'll get all the filenames based on those numbers, and move them

```
cd /path/to/directory
mv -t /path/to/new_directory "${myarray[@]/#/filename_}"
```

After this... honestly, I got bored. Stack Overflow is about helping people who make a good start at a problem, and you've done zero work toward figuring this out (other than writing "I promise I tried google").

I don't even understand what

> Run a command from the list of files the files from the list of numbers

means.

To rename them sequentially (once you've moved them), you'll want to do something based on this code:

```
for i in $(ls); do
    *your stuff here*
done
```

You should be able to research and figure stuff out. You might have to do some bash tutorials, [here's a reasonable starting place](https://guide.bash.academy/)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no programming experience and have 2 weeks of working with Linux. Not to mention this is my first StackOverflow post, so I'm not entirely familiar with how the entire community works. Had I have known, I would have submitted a list of the places I looked on reddit, google, various forums, etc. Much like yourself, I too am an answerer on Socratic for chemistry and physics problems. 
The problem is, is that I do not know enough about programming to succintly ask what I am looking for. In all honesty, thank you.

Comment: I understand, but generally it's a lot easier to help someone with a small, distinct question that they've already showed their attempt on, both so you have template code to work with and so you know their skill level. Since you have no experience, I could do it for you and post your answer, but you wouldn't learn anything (let's be real, I sincerely doubt you understand how the code I did post works). If you have questions like this, it's likely you'll have to work with linux in the future, and you should learn the basics so you can eventually help yourself instead of posting every time.